# friend request handling database

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I was handling friend requests in my react app using mysql database, my question is if I want to get all friends of the user with id 21 which are 28,27,30 in this picture below, how can I handle it, in mysql, which sql command should i use for it?

I appreciate any help

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wanted to list the friends of *id=21.
I think you should use UNION

```
SELECT receiver_id AS friend_id 
FROM table WHERE sender_id = 21
UNION
SELECT sender_id AS friend_id 
FROM table WHERE receiver_id = 21
```

Answer (score 2):

So you want all the `*id=21` users, and then in the result you want the result that isn't 21.

```
SELECT IF(sender_id=21, receiver_id, sender_id) AS friend
FROM table
WHERE sender_id=21 OR receiver_id=21
```